# What is the effect of placing an array after a function call?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var config = require('./server/config/config.js')[env];
```

My question is about the second line. I've never seen syntax where you have an array after a function call. What is the effect or significance of [env]?

Comment: That's not an array - it's an application of the `[ ]` operator, which extracts property values from objects (including arrays). It's not *creating* an array, in other words, it's getting something out of one (or out of an object of some sort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), not an array. An object followed by `[variable]` is used to dynamically access a property from an object. It's a dynamic equivalent to `config['development']`, allowing you to select the property at runtime.

You can break the line down into:

```
var config = require('./server/config/config.js');
config[env];
```

Combined with the `var env` line, it will:

1. Set `env` to the value of the `NODE_ENV` environment variable or `'development'` if the variable is unset.
2. Load the `./server/config/config.js` file.
3. Retrieve the `env` property from the config file.

For example, if your config contains:

```
{
  "development": {foo: 3},
  "production": {foo: 19}
}
```

and don't set any environment variables, the line in question will fetch the `"development"` block from the config.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a member object access using bracket notation, where `env` will supposedly contain the name of the module's property to retrieve. No arrays are created.

```
var config_module = require('./server/config/config.js');
var config = config_module[env];
```

Answer (score 0):

The second line requiring the config.js file looks like it is pulling in a config object. The square bracket notation in this case looks like it is used to access a property of this object based on the current environment. whether production, dev, etc.

Comment: It's not instantiating anything. The file is loaded and parsed, then it's a simple property access.

Comment: property of a javascript object no?

Comment: I've edited the answer to clear up wording. Does this sound more correct?